# How to change uitableview frame and keep sectionIndexbar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView with sectionIndexbar. I'm change UITableView in run time like this.

```
             CGRect frame = tbleView.frame;
             frame.size.height -= MapHeight;
             frame.origin.y+=MapHeight;
             tbleView.frame = frame;
```

But after I resizing table it's sectionIndexbar automatically hiding. I want to keep sectionIndexbar after I resizing UITableView. How can I do that?

Comment: What's a sectionIndexBar? Can you maybe give a bit more information, e.g. screenshots or more code? Are you using interface builder / storyboards to set up your view or do you do this programmatically?

Comment: I mean as sectionIndexbar you can see it iOS contact application, contact list right side. Alphabetical order index bar.

Comment: Did you try `[tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles]`?

Comment: I don't have experience with this, I was just reading through the docs and thought this could be helpful.

Comment: @NikolasBurk thanks for your comment. But I tried reloadSectionIndexTitles. But It's not help for me.